# Regex ascii string matching

Tags: regex, string

A bit of an odd regex question.

The input looks something like this

(43,'tx','some ascii string, potentially containing anything.',0),(36,'ca','some ascii string, potentially containing anything.',1),(75,'ak','some ascii string, potentially containing anything.',4),(55,'tx','some ascii string, potentially containing anything.',4),(36,'ca','some ascii string, potentially containing anything.',1),(66,'tx','some ascii string, potentially containing anything.',4),(99,'tx','some ascii string, potentially containing anything.',4);

The goal is to match all sequences containing (int, 'tx', 'ascii string', int)

My regex so far looks like this:

(([0-9]+,'tx','[\x00-\x7F]+',0))

It works to a point but stumbles on the repeated sequence at the end of the test string.

It finds 3 matches:

1. (43,'tx','some ascii string, potentially containing anything.',0)
2. (55,'tx','some ascii string, potentially containing anything.',4)

but returns the last two sequences as a single match

3. (66,'tx','some ascii string, potentially containing anything.',4),(99,'tx','some ascii string, potentially containing anything.',4)

What nuance am I overlooking?

Thanks!

Comment: I modified the regex to (\([0-9]+,'tx','[\x00-\x26 \x28-\x7F]+',0\)) and that seemed to work. I suspect it's not optimal but I'll work on that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that?

```
\([0-9]+,'tx','[^']*',[0-9]+\)
```

Comment: Thank you! Much cleaner.